# Multilevel logistic mixed model

Tags: mixed-model, categorical-data, multilevel-analysis

I have a survey over 14 schools. In each school, 9 to 11 students were interviewed for a comparison of two items A and B, which one they prefer. The outcome Y is a binary variable with 1 if a student prefer item A (compared with B) and 0 otherwise. Four variables have been measured: "School_Status" and "School_size" at school-level and "Age" and "English_proficiency" at student-level. School_Status has 3 levels, School_size 3 levels, Age 2 levels and English_proficiency 2 levels. The total number of observation was 155.

I used the following SAS glimmix code:

```
Proc glimmix;
    class School_Status School_size Age English_proficiency;
    model Y (event='1')= School_Status School_size Age English_proficiency / s dist=binary;
    random intercept  Age English_proficiency / type=un sub=school;
run ;
```

It did not converge.

When I used instead:

```
Proc glimmix method=laplace;
```

I received the following message:

ERROR: QUANEW Optimization cannot be completed

Grateful if someone could help.

Comment: Start with a simpler model (fewer predictors), simpler correlation structure, and  build up from there. You might also have problems if $P(Y=1)$ is close to 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your mixed model includes both fixed and random effects for both student and school level variables. This makes no sense. Random intercept should take *identifiers* for student and school whereas "age" and "class size" e.g. would go into the model statement as *fixed effects*. (please NAME your variables intuitively next time). Chances are, you broke your model because it's specified incorrectly. It's also not clear that you actually have repeated measures within student. Unless there are replications within the student *identifier*, school is the only cluster level variable *identifier* that should go in the random intercepts specification.

Comment: School-level variables as "Class size" and "Sector (private or not)" are both in fixed and random effects as in [link](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/seminars/sas_mlm/mlm_sas_seminar.htm). There are no replications within the student identifier

Comment: You cannot estimate random effects for those school-level variables. In the link you provided, no school-level variables are used as random effects.

Comment: Ok @Wolfgang and @AdamO. Sorry, indeed it was estimated random effects for student-level variables. In [link](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/seminars/sas_mlm/mlm_sas_seminar.htm), they have `random intercept cses / subject = school type = un gcorr;` in Model 4 where "cses" is at student-level